# Loss of a LSTM implemented in Keras with TF2 backend keeps a constant and the parameters are basically not learned while training on a large dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, lstm, chatbot

We are implementing this following architecture in Tensorflow 2. RNN means LSTM in this model.

[image: Dual Encoder LSTM]

This model is used to realize a retrieval-based chatbot found in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.08909.pdf) and this [blog](http://www.wildml.com/2016/07/deep-learning-for-chatbots-2-retrieval-based-model-tensorflow/). The blog author has a [working model](https://github.com/dennybritz/chatbot-retrieval) written in tf1.

Our Colab notebook can be accessed [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cOTl4lK9nFNOxi5uoNzucQ1vD9mr-i5C). And the model architecture output from our code is

[image: this]

The ? symbol means batch_size we can predefine. 160 is the sentence length, which means the repetitions of the LSTM network, since we feed the LSTM one word at a time. 256 is the output shape of the LSTM network. The training dataset looks like this

[image]

This model was claimed to be working while training on a Ubuntu Corpus dataset with 1M records. However, when we train our model, the loss remains at 0.6931 after 2~3 iterations and we assume then the parameters, especially M, are not learned during training. We had the model run for 12 hours and the loss did not decrease at all. Here is the output from training

```
Now training the model...
Train on 1000000 samples
 999936/1000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6938(195600,)
1000000/1000000 [==============================] - 2111s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.6938
Train on 1000000 samples
 999936/1000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.7739(195600,)
1000000/1000000 [==============================] - 2106s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.7739
Train on 1000000 samples
 999936/1000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6939(195600,)
1000000/1000000 [==============================] - 2163s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.6939
Train on 1000000 samples
 999936/1000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6932(195600,)
1000000/1000000 [==============================] - 2101s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.6932
Train on 1000000 samples
 999936/1000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6931(195600,)
1000000/1000000 [==============================] - 2099s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.6931
Train on 1000000 samples
 999936/1000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6932(195600,)
1000000/1000000 [==============================] - 2098s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.6932
Train on 1000000 samples
 999936/1000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6931(195600,)
1000000/1000000 [==============================] - 2102s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.6931
Train on 1000000 samples
 999936/1000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6931(195600,)
1000000/1000000 [==============================] - 2097s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.6931
Train on 1000000 samples
 999936/1000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6931(195600,)
1000000/1000000 [==============================] - 2107s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.6931
Train on 1000000 samples
 999936/1000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6931(195600,)
1000000/1000000 [==============================] - 2103s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.6931
Train on 1000000 samples
 999936/1000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6931(195600,)
1000000/1000000 [==============================] - 2103s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.6931
Train on 1000000 samples
 999936/1000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6931(195600,)
1000000/1000000 [==============================] - 2092s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.6931
Train on 1000000 samples
 999936/1000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6931(195600,)
1000000/1000000 [==============================] - 2099s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.6931
Train on 1000000 samples
 999936/1000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6931(195600,)
1000000/1000000 [==============================] - 2099s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.6931
Train on 1000000 samples
 999936/1000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6931(195600,)
1000000/1000000 [==============================] - 2096s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.6931
Train on 1000000 samples
 999936/1000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6931(195600,)
1000000/1000000 [==============================] - 2125s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.6931
Train on 1000000 samples
 999936/1000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6931(195600,)
1000000/1000000 [==============================] - 2132s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.6931
Train on 1000000 samples
  33792/1000000 [>.............................] - ETA: 24:23 - loss: 0.6931
```

However, our model will work if we truncate our dataset to 100,000 records, which means the loss will be decreasing steadily.

What could be the reason that this model could train on a small dataset but not on a large dataset?

Thanks.

Comment: The model may be too simple to converge on a complex dataset.

Comment: Hi Zabir thanks for your comment. This model was introduced in a publication and previously implemented successfully by the author of a blog mentioned in this question, so I guess there must be something wrong in our implementation :'(